# How can I display an image from a website without getting an error 403?

Tags: python, image, url, web-scraping

I am trying to display an image in my jupyter notebook project in order to build a graphical interface, but when I try to use a url (I can insert the url into my browser to see the image directly), it won't let me display it and returns a 403 error. Is there any way around it or am I missing something regarding displaying the file itself?

```
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.core.display import HTML 
x = Image(url= "https://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=%24NAA200R&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=0&r=1620689696568.png")[Here is the result I got from running the cell][1]
```

[Click to the see the Issue when trying to use the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwvNh.png)

[results from running the cell within the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkiO5.png)

Comment: it basically says that you are not authorized to access this image , you can read more about http 403 here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: The site might require a login, or it might require a legitimate browser ID, or it might only allow the images when you're viewing one of their pages.  The very obvious answer, of course, is to bring it up in your browser, right click, and "save image as" to store it on your computer.

Comment: It is only one of multiple pictures I would like to display on the notbook and manually downloading them would take too much time, as for a login the image is freely displayable via the link itself. Is there a way to create an instance within the cell to down and display the image or something similar? thank you for the help?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the header on request, you can try the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

import requests
url="https://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=%24NAA200R&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=0&r=1620689696568.png"
my_header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=my_header)
print(f"Response :{response.status_code}")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I created a solution myself creating a function to run through it. Very nice to see your solution works as well. The header really did seem like the main issue! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I could not display the picture directly but could print it, so instead of calling the image directly I create a function that will download the picture and display it with the variable being the needed link so I can use it for the few links I need. It isn´t as clean as I would like it to be but it solve the 403 issue in this case.

```
import urllib.request
from IPython.display import Image


def display_tool(x):
 image_url = x
 filename = "display.jpg"

 req = urllib.request.build_opener()
 req.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)')]
 urllib.request.install_opener(req)

 urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, filename)

 return Image(filename="display.jpg") 
 

display_tool("https://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=%24NAA200R&p=D&b=5&g=0&id=0&r=162069503175")
```

[Click to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWd9e.png)